# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) - Rpy2

Tags: python, r, pycharm, cross-validation, rpy2

I have searched a lot for this error, on stack overflow and other websites but I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem.

Basically, I have a program that is in `python`, and I am using python's module [rpy2](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for communicating with some `R` functions, from python.

The problem is that when I run the code, sometimes, but not always I encounter this error. I am on windows. Sometimes when I restart my PC this code runs more exercises, but then eventually this error pops up again. What should I do ?

I have `python 3.6.7`, with `PyCharm 2018.3.3`. However I doubt the problem is from `PyCharm` because when I run my program from the `cmd` the same thing happens, except that the program halts directly ***without*** notifying me with the message "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)". This message only appears in PyCharm, but still.

I have `rpy2 version 2.9.5`

**Code description**

I do know, relatively, which part of the code is doing this, but I cannot optimize it more. In other words, In this part of the code, inside cross validation, I am over populating each of the train and validation sets in a certain way, and in order to do that, I am combining both X_train and y_train back into one data frame, overpopulating this data frame, and then getting back the updated, overpopulated, X_train and y_train, and performing my analysis on these overpopulated ones. I think combining both into `numpy` arrays into a `pandas` dataframe and then un-combining back is creating this memory error. Also its important to note that this is happening in each fold, and I'm doing a 10-folds-10-repeats cross validation. However, even when I run this on a Desktop PC rather than on my laptop the same thing happens, knowing that I have plenty of GBs left on my own laptop. I am doubting this is a python/rpy2 error ??

**Code snippet**

```
# I am calling this function inside each fold
df_combined = self.prepare_data(X_train, y_train)
```

and then after calling `prepare_data()` I do as follows:

```
# THE apply_f1(), apply_f2(), apply_f3(), and apply_f4() ARE THE FUNCTIONS
# THAT USE rpy2 INTERNALLY
if self.f1:
       X_train_inner, y_train_inner = self.apply_f1(df_combined)

elif self.f2:
        X_train_inner, y_train_inner = self.apply_f2(df_combined)

elif self.f3:
        X_train_inner, y_train_inner = self.apply_f3(df_combined)

else:
    X_train_inner, y_train_inner = self.apply_f4(df_combined)
```

The `prepare_data()` function:

```
    def prepare_data(self, X_train, y_train):
        '''
        concatenates X_train_inner and y_train_inner into one, and make them a data frame
        so we are able to process the data frame by SMOGN, RandUnder, GN, or SMOTER
        '''

        # reshape + rename
        X_train_samp = X_train
        y_train_samp = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)

        # combine two numpy arrays together into one numpy array
        combined = np.concatenate((X_train_samp, y_train_samp), axis=1)

        # transform X_train + y_train into a pandas dataframe
        column_names = self.other + [self.target_variable]
        df_combined = pd.DataFrame(combined, columns=column_names)

        # convert the combined pandas dataframe to R Data.Frame
        df_combined = pandas2ri.py2ri(df_combined)

        return df_combined
```

Comment: Do you know approximately wherein the code or does it complete everything?  If not, you may have to add some logging to it so we can narrow down where it prematurely exits

Comment: @JimmySmith Yes I do know where approximately, this is an old code that I did a month ago but now I added a small part; it is after I added this part things started going crazy. The code is correct, but this memory error is popping, because when it completes it completes correctly.

Comment: @JimmySmith I tried to divide this part that I added into chunks, so rather than having everything in one place, I divided my code into functions and started calling these functions, but that didn't work out.

Comment: The latest rpy2 release is 3.2.5. Consider updating your version.

Comment: @lgautier I have used previously this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2) to install rpy2 using the most convenient wheel to my python's version. I tried now upgrading using ```pip install rpy2 --upgrade``` but I got the same old error ``` python setup egg_info``` ... any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: This one may be a matter of the hardware it's running on.  You refer to a memory error?  Is it only on 1 machine you ever see the error?  What we need is the last bit of code, before it bombs.

Comment: @JimmySmith I tried my code on several machines and it behaves the same. I called it a ```memory``` error because I think this is window's famous Heap error ?

Comment: @JimmySmith I added a code snippet to demonstrate the problem more specifically. Please find the updates above

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same error message "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" with PyCharm 2021.1.

It happened because I selected Python 3.9 as an interpreter, while PyCharm was actually trying to use Python 3.10. And actually I had only Python 3.8 installed.

As far as I am concerned, the error disappeared after I selected Python 3.8 as an interpreter.

Comment: Hi @Jim J, This problem is long ago now :p,but I remember that the solution was very weird and it had to do with the pandas version installed at my PC. I had to downgrade it. I was using python ```3.6.7```